# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting after choosing different NVidia Proprietary driver. Failed to start NVidia Persistence Daemon

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

Getting [FAILED] - Failed to start NVidia Persistence Daemon.  And the screen went black with the cursor blinking in 20.04.

My videos were getting stuck and not playing properly in the VLC. So, I tried to update the Nvidia driver. I went to the Additional Drivers tab, it had "using (proprietory, tested) selected by default, but I selected the second option which was having just (proprietory) and clicked apply changes. I got the dialog box to give a secure boot password and I gave it.
Upon restart, I got a small blue box with options "Continue to boot", Open MDK, and one more option. I chose "Continue to boot". And the system started to boot but got stuck with a cursor blinking in black screen. It's not successfully booting.
I searched this forum and as suggested in other posts, tried to disable the Secure boot option and restarted again.
This time, I pressed Ctl + Alt + F1 and I could see the statuses. In that I saw the message [FAILED] - Failed to start NVidia Persistence Daemon.  And the screen went black with the cursor blinking.

I don't get the GRUB screen to go to the terminal mode to uninstall or update the driver.
How can I fix it? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix using the below steps:

While booting, keep pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> after the manufacturer logo and before the Ubuntu logo appears.

The GRUB Menu should appear. But for me I got the GRUB command line instead.

```
grub>
```

Type `normal` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. And keep pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> again.
Will get the GRUB menu now.

Choose the line that starts with "Advance Options:" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
You will get a Recovery Menu box:
Choose the option

```
root  - Drop to root shell prompt.
```

You will get the root command prompt at the bottom of the screen.
Type the below commands to fix it, i.e, to uninstall/remove the Nvidia proprietary drivers and install the default drivers.

```bsh
ubuntu-drivers list  # To see the list of drivers
apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
reboot # to restart the system.
```

The Ubuntu was rebooting again as usual.